# transition parameter in afterModel emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i don't understand why the `afterModel` method get a `transition` parameter, and what its represent (yeah a transition from one page to the other, but in `afterModel` method there is no transition running, and that the prupose of `afterModel`, starting a transition if required, using model data.)

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_afterModel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `afterModel` hook is the third of the three model hookes, which all run *before* the transition is done.

So the transition in `afterModel` is the same then in `beforeModel`.

The difference is that sometimes you need the model to decide if you want to abort the transition and redirect to somewhere else or not.

A example could be a `/userEdit/:user_id` route where admins can edit all users and normal users only can edit their own user. In the `beforeModel` you could check if the the user is admin and if not but you can't abort the transition based on information on the model. In the `atferModel` hook you can do exactly this, and save the transition away to may retry it later, for example after the user got admin privileges.

The router does *not* enter the route after the Promise returned by the `afterModel` hook resolves.